# How to deal with folders in a File Cabinet by script?

Tags: google-apps-script, attachment, directory, google-sites

I'm interacting with a Google Site File Cabinet by script. No problem to add some new attachments to a given page.

But I would like to deal with Folders in File Cabinet by script.
Is it possible? If yes, how? I can't find documentation about this topic.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For manipulating files and folders in Google Drive using Google Apps Scripts please see [DocsList Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/)

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your answer but I'm not talking about Google Drive.
I'm talking about File Cabinet in Google Sites.
See this topic [link](http://edutraining.googleapps.com/Training-Home/module-5-sites/chapter-3/4-3).
How to create Folders in a Google Site File Cabinet using script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Johan take a look at the [*page class*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page) where there is a [`createFileCabinetPage(title, name, html)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#createFileCabinetPage%28String,String,String%29) method which you might be looking for, there are also some examples.